# Looping XML Animator with break at the end

Tags: android

For an AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat, I am trying to implement the following animation :

1. Go up during 200ms
2. Go down during 200ms
3. Do nothing for 600ms
4. Go back to 1 to loop forever

As this is for an AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat, the Animator has to be written in XML. You can't add listener on the animation of the compat version of animated vector drawable ...

With pure XML, i can do either step 1-2-4 or 1-2-3. I can't make the an animator with the 600ms break then looping.

This is how I do 1-2-4 :

```
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="200"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
    android:propertyName="translateY"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:repeatCount="-1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:valueTo="-20"
    android:valueType="floatType"/>
```

And here is how i do 1-2-3 but this is not looping ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="sequentially">

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="200"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:propertyName="translateY"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="-20"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="200"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:propertyName="translateY"
        android:valueFrom="-20"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="600"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:propertyName="translateY"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:valueType="floatType"/>
</set>
```

How can i easily loop an animator set with pure XML ?

Thanks

Comment: Because for vector drawable compat you can't set programmatically the animator for each target.

Comment: You can add listeners to AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat now https://stackoverflow.com/a/46459743/4672107