# How to restart android AnimatedVectorDrawables animations?

Tags: android, animation, svg, android-vectordrawable

I have a kinda complex vector drawable that I want to animate.
I used [@RomanNurik's](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidIconAnimator/) web tool to create the animation from a svg

That gives me a valid `<animated-vector>` according to [the documentatios](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html). It's an "all in one" XML file.

The xml has the drawable divided in 2 groups, each group containing 2 paths and has also added 4 animations, just as follows:

```
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
    <aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
        <vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:width="56dp"
            android:height="56dp"
            android:viewportHeight="56.0"
            android:viewportWidth="56.0">
            <group
                android:name="group_1"
                android:pivotX="25"
                android:pivotY="25">
                <path
                    android:name="path_3_1"
                    ... />
                <path
                    android:name="path"
                    ... />
            </group>
            <group
                android:name="group"
                android:pivotX="25"
                android:pivotY="25">
                <path
                    android:name="path_1"
                    ... />
                <path
                    android:name="path_2"
                    ... />
            </group>
        </vector>
    </aapt:attr>
    <target android:name="path">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
                <objectAnimator
                    android:name="path"
                    ... />
                <objectAnimator
                    android:name="path"
                  .../>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="group_1">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
                <objectAnimator
                    android:name="group_1"
                    ... />
                <objectAnimator
                    android:name="group_1"
                    ... />
                <objectAnimator
                    android:name="group_1"
                    ... />
                <objectAnimator
                    android:name="group_1"
                    ... />
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="group">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
                <objectAnimator
                    android:name="group"
                    ... />
                <objectAnimator
                    android:name="group"
                    ... />
                <objectAnimator
                    android:name="group"
                    ... />
                <objectAnimator
                    android:name="group"
                    ... />
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
    <target android:name="path_3_1">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
                <objectAnimator
                    android:name="path_3_1"
                    ... />
                <objectAnimator
                    android:name="path_3_1"
                    ... />
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
</animated-vector>
```

### **Issue number 1:**

I cannot use `android:repeatCount="infinite"` since the `ObjectAnimators` have different `android:duration` and `android:startOffset` values, that would mess up the animation after some runs. So the way to go is repeat it programmatically. Fair enough.

### **Issue number 2:**

Neither AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat or AnimatedVectorDrawable have a method that says animation should loop.

### **Issue number 3:**

[AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.html) does not have a `registerAnimationCallback()` so I can listen to `onAnimationEnd` and restart the animation myself. At this point, I gave up on retrocompatibility.

### **Issue number 4:**

The current implementation I have that uses `registerAnimationCallback()` from `AnimatedVectorDrawable` only works at android API 25, even though the methods were added in API 23

```
AnimatedVectorDrawable drawable = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) context().getDrawable(R.drawable.long_press_anim);
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
drawable.registerAnimationCallback(new Animatable2.AnimationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Drawable drawable) {
        super.onAnimationEnd(drawable);
        ((AnimatedVectorDrawable) drawable).start();
    }
});
drawable.start();
```

In API 23 and 24 the animation runs as a one-shot, it does not repeat.

Any ideas how to solve this? I;m about to give up and use a shit png sequence instead.

Comment: postDelay a handler with the proper delay ... it's the only solution

Comment: I tried that before with AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat and it didn't work. But I can confirm it works with VectorDrawableCompat at API 21-25

Comment: Now support library has [registerAnimationCallback()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.html#registerAnimationCallback(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.support.graphics.drawable.Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback))

Answer (score 17):

The official and working answer is here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64591234

This code works with >= API 16 (probably also 14-15). I'm using support library 26.1.0 and `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` (so I can refer to a vector drawable in xml without crashing)

```
animatedVector = AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(getContext(), R.drawable.animated_clock);
ringingAlarmImage.setImageDrawable(animatedVector);
final Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
animatedVector.registerAnimationCallback(new Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(final Drawable drawable) {
        mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                animatedVector.start();
            }
        });
    }
});
animatedVector.start();
```

Comment: There is a small explanation in the link. Something to do with technicalities on when things happen in the threads

Comment: Worked Fine ;) Thanks.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer and needs more upvotes! it is the only way I could get my animation to loop too. with the handler it now works. Android docs do not specify this behavior!

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue so I did this:

```
// setup and set animation
AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat animatedVector = AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(context, R.drawable.listening_vector_anim);
imageView.setImageDrawable(animatedVector);

// loop animation!
new Thread(() -> {
    while (imageView.isAttachedToWindow()) {
        try {
            imageView.post(() -> animatedVector.start());
            Thread.sleep(2000); //depends on your animation duration
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

This thread will die when the ImageView detach from window.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving a few tips

Issue Number 1: android:repeatCount="0" to make it infinite. and android:repeatMode="restart" or "reverse".

Issue Number 2: Looping is there in ObjectAnimator. The above, under Number one is the same.

Issue Number 3:Listener is there on ObjectAnimator. If you add a listener you can watch onAnimationEnd or onAnimationStart.

Instead of a single file if you opt for the other alternative of 3 files as given in documentation for AnimatedVectorDrawable you can feel comfortable to handle.

The three are 1. VectorDrawable, 2. AnimatedVectorDrawable and 3.ObjectAnimator

The AnimatedVectorDrawable links the other two.

There is a good article in Ray Wenderlich's site with a rocket and a doge animation at : https://www.raywenderlich.com/173345/android-animation-tutorial-with-kotlin (with java code).

You may also read the article "Introduction to Icon animation Techniques" by Mr.Alex Lockwood at : https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/11/introduction-to-icon-animation-techniques.html
The source code is also available in GitHub.